# 9-bit subtraction using 9-bit adder

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I've learnt from a CS book that

> If we try to perform a 9-bit subtraction using a 9-bit full adder, it will not(always) work.
>
> The referenced logic circuit is supposed to be an extended version of this:
> [8-bit adder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaKbr.jpg)

I was curious to know why it wouldn't work, and if there are any examples to support this statement. I've searched this topic in numerous search engines but found no resource regarding this. Could you please provide the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use an adder for subtraction, you have to complement the second operand and add one:

```
A - B = A + ~B + 1
```

The increment by one can cause an overflow.

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor).